How can I ignore text with Tesseract if all characters are not in whitelist?
I'm using Tesseract both on my Windows 10 machine and in the Docker container based on the alpine:3.21 image.
Windows tesseract --version is
tesseract v5.5.0.20241111
 leptonica-1.85.0
  libgif 5.2.2 : libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 3.0.4) : libpng 1.6.44 : libtiff 4.7.0 : zlib 1.3.1 : libwebp 1.4.0 : libopenjp2 2.5.2
 Found AVX2
 Found AVX
 Found FMA
 Found SSE4.1
 Found libarchive 3.7.7 zlib/1.3.1 liblzma/5.6.3 bz2lib/1.0.8 liblz4/1.10.0 libzstd/1.5.6
 Found libcurl/8.11.0 Schannel zlib/1.3.1 brotli/1.1.0 zstd/1.5.6 libidn2/2.3.7 libpsl/0.21.5 libssh2/1.11.0

Alpine Linux tesseract --version is
tesseract 5.5.0
 leptonica-1.84.1
  libgif 5.2.2 : libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 3.0.4) : libpng 1.6.44 : libtiff 4.7.0 : zlib 1.3.1 : libwebp 1.4.0
 Found AVX2
 Found AVX
 Found FMA
 Found SSE4.1
 Found OpenMP 201511

Having a sample image with the text "Hello"

and executing the command
tesseract img.png stdout -l eng -c "tessedit_char_whitelist=1234567890"
I'm getting different results on different platforms. On Windows, the command returns an empty string (which is reasonable since there are no numbers on the image), whereas on Alpine Linux it anyway tries to match text with characters from the whitelist, returning a weird 19  0 string.
I'm aware that slightly different versions of Tesseract may produce drastically different results, but the question is how to force ignoring a text if all its chars are not in the whitelist. Which special parameter should be added to the tesseract command to achieve a Windows-like behavior everywhere?
